# Disable selected options on dynamically added fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jsfiddle: [DYNAMIC ADDED FIELDS](https://jsfiddle.net/Lden478L/70/)

Well, all things are working well but i want to add some salting on it, i want to find a way of disabling selected options so that they can't be selected again. Kindly provide me any work around. I have already tried to add this

```
var option = $("option[value='" + value + "']", this);
option.attr("disabled","disabled");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [.prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method instead.

In your case: `option.prop("disabled","disabled");`

Comment: kindly, can you update for me the fiddle as you suggest

Comment: @HackZaid [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lden478L/78/), although you would need to implement logic so that when you delete the last one and there are multiple fields, the now latest one becomes enabled. This is the line of code that I added btw: ``$("select").eq(-2).prop("disabled","disabled");``.

Comment: You'r close to what i want, what i really want is disable the option value, say `<option value=1>Option 1</option><option value=2>Option 2</option>` so, if option `Option 1` is selected, in the next dynamic add field it should be disabled, only left with `Option 2`

Comment: In any case I provided you with the main method you require in order to disable the fields, you can now yourself add the necessary logic as to when and which fields get disabled.